# Can't import sklearn ([WinError 126] The specified module could not be found)

Tags: python, pytorch

`from sklearn import datasets`

I can't import `sklearn`

here is the error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-13-f9e6334b9a20> in <module>
  1 import torch
  2 import numpy as np
   ----> 3 from sklearn import datasets
  4 
  5 X_numpy, y_numpy = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=1, noise=20, 
  random_state=1)

 c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
 78     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
 79     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 80     from .base import clone
 81     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
 82 

c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
 19 from . import __version__
 20 from ._config import get_config
---> 21 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
 22 from .utils.validation import check_X_y
 23 from .utils.validation import check_array

c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
 18 import warnings
 19 import numpy as np
---> 20 from scipy.sparse import issparse
 21 
 22 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32

c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>
102 
103 # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 104 from . import _distributor_init
105 
106 __all__ += _num.__all__

c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
 59             os.chdir(libs_path)
 60             for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(libs_path, '*dll')):
 ---> 61                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
 62         finally:
 63             os.chdir(owd)

 c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
362 
363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
365         else:
366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

when I type `pip install sklearn` I get Requirement already satisfied:

`Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (0.0) Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from sklearn) (0.23.1) Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (0.15.1) Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (2.1.0) Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.18.5) Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in c:\users\kadiem alqazzaz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.5.0)`

so why can't I use sklearn, any help is appreciated thanks.

EDIT: when I import `sklearn` in cmd it works with no issues, however, when I run using Jupyter Notebook I get the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure  OpenSlide DLL in your library search path

Otherwise:
download the OpenSlide Windows binaries, then you need to add the 'bin' folder to your environmental path

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when you have more than one version of Python on your machine.

Try to install sklearn with

```
python -m pip install sklearn
```

If this installs a new `sklearn` it means that your `pip` and `python` have different paths and `pip` simply installs `sklearn` for another Python version that you have in your system.